# Secure login approach when the application and database are separate?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, hash, passwords

- Passwords are hashed using php password_function()
- All database calls are done through stored procedures
- There is a stored procedure for logging in that takes two parameters: user email and hashed password

I don't have access to setup/modify stored procedures, but I don't have a way (that I'm aware of) to pass in the same hashed password for the stored procedure to compare with. Would another stored procedure that returns a password hash from the user's email be a correct approach? Trying to convince the DBA on this, there are unsure concerns about exposing the hash to the application (not publicly).

Answer (score 0):

I would just keep all the hash comparisons on the database side. Even though it really doesn't make it any less secure between PHP and the server if you returned the hash from the DB. Unless there is a massive security flaw in your PHP code.